# Building an intellisense application using WPF .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5

I want to build an app with intellisense feature using WPF .NET 3.5. Where and how do I start off?

Thanks

Comment: There are two ways you can start: either hire a developer, or enroll in a development course.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off using a commercial control. Something like this can be extremely difficult to write.

Here's an example product: http://www.actiprosoftware.com/products/controls/wpf/syntaxeditor